# How would I go about justifying text in a UIWebView?

Tags: ios, swift, uiwebview

I am loading a local HTML string into a UIWebView but it is not justified.

How can I make my text justified ?

P.S. Don't mind the stupid text, it's for a comedy journal at my university.

[image: Screenshot]

**EDIT 1: still not working**

```
        let justifiedArticleContent = "<p style=\"text-align:justify\"> \(editorialArticleContentThroughSegue) </p>"

    editorialDetailWebView.loadHTMLString(justifiedArticleContent, baseURL: nil)
```

[image: Screenshot 2]

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn some CSS:

```
let htmlString = "<p style=\"text-align:justify\">As is the same with many students...</p>"
```

Comment: I actually learned the basics of CSS at the beginning of this year. I just didn't think that I would be able to use it in Xcode. I also had no idea what to write precisely for it to work